# npm dotenv environment variables not recognized in nodejs module

Tags: node.js, npm, module, environment-variables

Here is my project structure:
[image: project structure]

**package.json**:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "nodemon $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION server/boot.js --exec babel-node",
     "start": "nodemon server/boot.js --exec babel-node",
     "build": "babel server -d dist/server",
     "serve": "node dist/server/boot.js"
   },
```

The main file is **server/boot.js**:

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import path from 'path';

dotenv.load({path: path.join(__dirname, '.env')});

import _ from 'underscore';
import configs from './config/index';
```

The **server/config/index.js** is only a barrel file that imports the other config files:

```
import app from './app';
import database from './database';

export default Object.assign({}, app, database);
```

In each of the config files I am not able to access any properties of the **process.env** object that are defined in the **.env** file.

Here is one of the config files for reference:

```
export default  {
    app: {
        host: process.env.HOST || 'localhost',
        port: process.env.PORT || 9000,
    }
}
```

Here **process.env.HOST** is undefined, but the key is present in the **.env** file.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

> process.env object that are defined in the .env file.

Can you please be more specific about the process.env file?

As per https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#rules the file should be in the format:

```
VAR1=value1
VAR2=value2
```

and not in

```
export default { 
    VAR1: 'value1', 
    VAR2: 'value2' 
}
```

Comment: It's important to note that the `dotenv` package does not allow for an optional `export` at the beginning of a line, which is a departure from what pretty much every other implementation does. That has tripped me up, and pull requests to bring the package in line with other languages have been explicitly rejected by the author.